# How to re-order datatable column names in a R-Shiny App?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am writing an App which displays data via datatable. Therefore different forms of text files from users are read in. It is often the case that the order of the columns is mixed up in this files, but the information in it is valid.
After displaying the data I want to do some plausibility routines and therefore I want to say: do XY with the data in "Column A". But if there is the wrong data (because of the wrong order of the columns) the plausibility is useless. Therefore I would like reorder the column names like: Column no. 3 is not 'Column A' but contains the data of 'column B', etc.

What I want to do now is to reorder the column names, not the entire column as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65424976/r-shiny-getting-information-from-datatable-with-js-in-shiny).
With the following code I am able to move the whole column, but how do I **only move** the **column names**?

**Edit:** Just to make things clear: no, I don't want to sort the columns while reading in the data. I want to read in the file as it is and just work with the datatable object. This is mainly because I don't know what kind of file i get and what kind of information is in there. So I first of all want to display what's in there and then have a closer look.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
      DTOutput("table")
      )

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
    output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris,
      rownames = FALSE,
      extensions = "ColReorder",
      options = list(
        colReorder = TRUE
      ),
     colnames = c("S-Length", "S-Width", "P-Length", "P-Width", "Species")
      )
  })
}
 
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)? Why not just reorder the columns as you load the text files?  (`dplyr::select` will do that for you.)

Comment: @Limey: Not it is not. I want to see the "wrong" order in the first place and afterwards rearrange the data.table (per drag & drop).

Comment: Could you just allow the edition of the column names? e.g. [How to edit column names in datatable function when running R shiny app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54756377/how-to-edit-column-names-in-datatable-function-when-running-r-shiny-app)

Comment: hi @julien.leroux5 Yes, that would be a possiblityand thanks for the advice. I've seen this post already a few days ago but actually I wanted to avoid this: mainly because many different people are using the app and I think it takes longer tame renaming the columns compared to "just" moving them. But I might reconsider using it, if noone comes up with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess I found a solution myself via the package `shinyjqui`.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyjqui) # of course you need to install the package first, if you've never used it before

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjqui::orderInput("order",
                        "some order",
                        items = c("S-Length", "S-Width", "P-Length", "P-Width", "Species")),
  tags$br(),
  DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
 
  output$table <- renderDT({
    
    names(iris) <- input$order
    
    datatable(
      iris,
      rownames = FALSE,
      extensions = "ColReorder",
      options = list(
        colReorder = TRUE
      )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

***Note:*** With `names(iris) <- input$order` I've directly changed the columns' names of the data set and not just the names of the datatable, because I wanted to further access the columns by its (new) names. One could also "only" change the (displayed) names for the datatable.

***Edit:*** btw, here is Stéphane Laurent's version (see answer above) modularized, in case anyone needs it.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)
library(DT)#

ui_modul <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    jqui_sortable( DTOutput(ns("dtable")), options = list(items= "thead th"))
  )
}

server_modul <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
        datatable(head(iris, 5))
      })      
    }
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  ui_modul("test")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  server_modul("test")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution works but the datatable is re-rendered each time you reorder the column names.

Here is a solution using `shinyjqui::jqui_sortable` with which the datatable is not re-rendered when one sorts the column names:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)
library(DT)


ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(head(iris, 5))
  })
  
  jqui_sortable("#dtable thead tr")
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: True, that's also a possibility. May I ask you if there is a specific reason why you're always using ```output[["some_output"]]``` instead of ```output$some_output```?

Comment: @micsky `output[["some_output"]]` has a better syntax highlighting in RStudio. This is more readable.